# How to find day of week in Suitescript

Tags: netsuite, dayofweek, suitescript

Hi Im new to suitescript. I want to find day of week from the Date. Is there any API's for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay(); //Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on
```